# jQuery DataTables default column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to include an invisible column in a jQuery DataTable that can be set to default `true` in place of a null or undefined encountered in the data source.

Say I am working with a 6-columns DataTable. The first 5 columns are visible. The 6th column is set to not be visible. And it must contain either a true or false, regardless of whether the data source object has the corresponding key. In the column definitions for the DataTable, I tried this but it did not work.

```
{ "defaultContent": true, "data": "existing", "visible": false }
```

According to the API, I think `defaultContent` works only when `data` is null. Maybe that's why it does not work. I have provided the HTML, JS data and JS code for initializing the DataTable. Notice that once the DataTable is loaded and rendered, I dynamically append a row and re-draw. The data for this row contains the 6th column property and that is gets set just fine.

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

JavaScript (data initialization):

```
var dataSet = [
    {'engine':'Webkit','browser':'Safari 1.2','platform':'OSX.3','version':'125.5','grade':'A'},
    {'engine':'Other browsers','browser':'All others','platform':'-','version':'-','grade':'U'}
];
```

JavaScript (DataTable creation and initialization):

```
$('#demo').html('<table class="display" id="example"></table>');

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "sortable" : false, "data": null, "defaultContent": "<button>Select</button>", "title" : "Choose"
        },
        { "title": "Engine", "data": "engine" },
        { "title": "Browser", "data": "browser" },
        { "title": "Platform", "data": "platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "data": "version", "class": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "data": "grade", "class": "center" },
        { "defaultContent": true, "data": "existing", "visible": false }
    ],
    initComplete: function(oSettings, json) {
      console.log('drawing complete');
      if (oSettings.fnRecordsTotal() > 1) {
        $('#example').DataTable().row.add({
          'engine' : 'Presto',
          'browser' : 'Opera 7.5',
          'platform' : 'Win 95+ / OSX.2+',
          'version' : '-',
          'grade' : 'A',
          'existing' : false
        }).draw();
      }
    }
} );
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webuser7/vbmueLwv/) for the above example. If you click on the Select button in the first two rows, it returns `undefined`. The Select button on the third row yields `false`. I want the first two rows' Select button to yield `true`.

How do I set a default value for the 6th (invisible) column if no key/value is provided in the data-set object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns undefined because `existing` not exists in `dataSet`. `dataSet` is static, `defaultContent` does not populate its value to the original `dataSet`. What you really want is the value of the hidden column, which will contain either `defaultContent` or dynamically added `existing` values.

```js
var row = $('#example').DataTable().row( $(this).parents('tr') ),
    index = row.index(),
    data = row.cell(index, 6).data();

alert(data);
```

will return `true`, `true` and `false`.  Forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vsx7uxnf/**

Comment: I agree that `defaultContent` does not affect the static `dataSet`. Maybe my fundamentals are lacking; was my code fetching the corresponding rendered DataTable row's data or the corresponding object from `dataSet`? The only difference appears to be that you are referencing data in a specific cell while I am referencing data corresponding to the entire row. Your code works, btw.

Comment: @WebUser, you are targeting `data.existing` - `alert(data.existing);` - which does not exists, therefore you get an `undefined`. It _would_ work, if you had `existing` in `dataSet` too, but you have not - that is the problem, thats why you must retrieve the value from the cell directly.

Comment: _was my code fetching the corresponding rendered DataTable row's data or the corresponding object from dataSet?_ - the corresponding object from dataSet.

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad - that helps. I had carelessly presumed that while defining the columns for the DataTable and establishing a default value, `data` represents the row and not the underlying `dataSet`. Upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: is there a way to specify a different content for the first column when dynamically adding the row? The column is configured to display a button, but I would like to show something else when adding a row via a API call. Sorry this is deviating from my original question, but I don't know if there is a way to take this thread into a chat or messaging system within StackOverflow!

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, regarding the question, see this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vsx7uxnf/4/** (if I understand correctly) just give the first column a name instead of `null`, and then target that name when you insert new rows dynamically (in the example an input box in inserted instead of the `defaultContent` button)